# What is the difference between gnuplot and AquaTerm?

Tags: gnuplot, x11, octave, quartz-graphics

What is the difference between AquaTerm and gnuplot.

Also is it true that Octave uses AquaTerm instead of X11?

I know AquaTerm might be more rendering of the actual graphic and gnuplot is probably the engine but what does that means?

Comment: Just curious--did you ever settle on one (i.e. Aquaterm or X11)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AquaTerm is a graphics renderer.  Basically, it is a library with an API with allows various programming languages to display graphics on the screen.  `gnuplot` is a plotting utility.  In a lot of ways, `gnuplot` functions like a special purpose programming language used for creating plots.  It is able to write those plots to a whole bunch of different devices ("terminals").  examples of some devices are files (png, pdf, postscript) printers and graphics libraries (X11, AquaTerm).  Ultimately, any graph that you can make with gnuplot + AquaTerm for the display on the backend *could* be made without gnuplot.  Gnuplot's purpose is to abstract the details of the output device away from the user as much as possible so that if you make a plot and display it using AquaTerm, you can then easily save that plot to a png file for future reference.  In reality, there are always some terminal dependent behaviours, but most of the time it doesn't actually matter.